# How do you deal with discrepancy in informality between dictionaries?

Tags: formality

Examples include creepy and blockheaded. They are informal by some dictionaries and not by others. How do you determine if they are informal? Is there a preferred dictionary for that? Suppose the audience is just expecting formality.

Dictionaries consults for creepy: OED (neutral (not informal)), Collins (informal), Macmillan (informal), and AHD (informal).

Dictionaries consults for blockheaded: Collins (derogatory (Informal?)), OED (neutral), Macmillan (informal), and AHD (neutral).

All right, I did not know Random house and MW does not label colloquialism. The point still stands though.

Comment: It would be helpful if you listed the dictionaries you consulted and what each one said.

Comment: 'They are ... not [informal] [according to] others.' Are you sure you're not claiming that these 'other' dictionaries are classifying these words as 'not informal' when the true situation is that they just don't specify register?

Comment: @AlanCarmack Just did.

Comment: @EdwinAshworth By that, do you mean the dictionaries entirely disregard labels? If so, no. I have listed the consulted dictionaries for clarification. Edit: All right, I sort of did with Random house. I'll remove that part.

Comment: To reviewers: I think this is a useful and on-topic question; don't close it - keep it in the ELU repository unless there's a duplicate. The gold standard for whether a word is considered to be an *English word* is to look for its dictionary listing. This question asks about the situation when dictionaries disagree. What then? Do we pick the most recent entry, the most popular or prestigious dictionary (by whatever ranking system is relevant), seek a higher authority, or simply pick any dictionary at our own discretion? I think this question fits squarely within English Language and Usage.

Comment: @Lawrence I agree it is somewhat related with English Language and Usage, but the problem is the question reads way too broad or could generate only primarily opinion-based answers. How do you deal with it? People have their own ways and they can't be a definitive answer. The best way to deal with it is ask "I found this word XYZ in A, B, C and D dictionaries, but some say it's informal and others don't". Is this word informal in this sentence? Also, you need to note that dictionaries don't get updated regularly to list formality or informality. We should not rely on dictionaries. My opinion.

Comment: Both CDO and ODO label 'creepy' as _informal_. I'd like to see the whole OED entry before I agree that there might be a problem here; all the other labellings concur with my own opinion. // I don't think anyone would disagree that the label _derogatory_ should be included with 'blockhead' (there is the playful usage too). The word would certainly not be found in a medical paper. Perhaps the implication is that the informal-formal continuum and the [overtly] derogatory - unmarked continuum are not orthogonal (so 'derogatory' is a sufficient label)....

Comment: But I'd certainly consider 'blockhead/ed' as lying far nearer the informal pole than the formal. You could try averaging the opinions of the various dictionary panels.

Comment: There are 3 Google hits for "If he were a blockhead". Many (but by no means all) of the hits for << "he's a blockhead" -Blake -proof >> show clear use of an informal (or slang) register.

Comment: Uh, "creepy" and "blockheaded" are informal, in that they would never be used in, eg, written laws, letters to the Queen, or any other strictly formal communications.  *How* informal they are is a separate question, and there is no "scale" for that.

Comment: Are you a native speaker of English? I ask only because  native speakers generally have a solid idea as to the formality of most words. And my answer might depend on whether you are a learner of English or a native speaker.

Comment: When in doubt I usually look it up on www.urbandictionary.com. And then often go for a synonym anyway...

Comment: blockhead, in the [OED](http://www.oed.com/view/Entry/20358?redirectedFrom=blockhead&); blockheaded in the [OED](http://www.oed.com/view/Entry/20359?redirectedFrom=blockheaded&).  From the definitions, it is clear that you wouldn't use these terms unless you were intentionally insulting someone.  That given, whether the terms are formal or informal is of secondary interest.

Comment: The main problem is that *formality* is a moving target. At points one might have considered stuff people write formal, or what politicians say in public or the nobility, you know on formal occasions. Dictionaries can only try to keep up with what people deem proper for such occasions.

Comment: @EdwinAshworth http://imgur.com/a/z4Dza

Comment: @AlanCarmack I am a native English speaker. I know what words sound informal or not but I always trust the dictionary before myself.

Answer (score 3):

Language is vague and dictionaries aren't perfect themselves (that is to say that the world is variable but also the record of the world is variable).

Dictionaries are references and not necessarily fully defining. What they specify is mostly to be not wrong. Not saying that a word is informal is not wrong, (also the editing decision of a particular dictionary may be to use attributes like informal only in extremes).

The way I deal with multiple definitions that differ for terms that I have no idea about is to consider such attributes as possibles. If all the definitions have the same attribute (say informal) the word is most likely informal. If one of many misses the attribute then maybe it is a mistake or maybe it is not extremely informal. If only one out of many has the attribute, maybe it is a mistake or maybe it is slightly informal. If none have the attribute, it probably isn't informal (but maybe it is slightly informal.

You're never entirely sure about anything ever, but you can only see the data that you have. If there is a discrepancy look at more data/sources/dictionaries.